# Qt: How to change a svg image at runtime

Tags: c++, windows, image, qt, svg

I have an a custom class of `QGraphicsSvgItem` namely `CloseItem`. The object of my custom class is added to `QGraphicsItemGroup`.

Now at hover event of my custom class svg item, I want to change the svg image.

**Code**

```
class CloseItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsSvgItem{

protected:
 QSvgRenderer *close;
 QSvgRenderer *closeHover;

public:
 CloseItem (QGraphicsItem * parent = 0) : QObject(), QGraphicsSvgItem(parent){
  close = new QSvgRenderer(QStringLiteral("img/x icon 16x16.svg"));
  closeHover = new QSvgRenderer(QStringLiteral("img/x icon hover 16x16.svg"));
  this->setSharedRenderer(close);
  this->setElementId("close");
 }

 void hoverEnterEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *e) override{
  this->setSharedRenderer(closeHover);
 }

 void hoverLeaveEvent(QGraphicsSceneHoverEvent *e) override{
  this->setSharedRenderer(close);
 }
};
```

**Problem:** Here, I am not getting svg image.

Comment: What's the problem, the svg image doesn't change on hover or no image is shown at all?

Comment: the svg image doesn't shown at all, I have also write code in constructor but its not shown at all.

Comment: If you comment the line " this->setElementId("close"); ", does the image show up?